# Convert glow::Framebuffer to u64

Tags: rust, egui

`egui::Image::new` can take a `User(u64)` as the first parameter. I have a glow::Framebuffer that I want to pass to the function like

`egui::Image::new(User(frame_buffer), egui::Vec2::new(1280.0, 720.0));`

It looks like `glow::Frambuffer` is a `NativeFramebuffer(NonZeroU32)`. How do I convert a `glow::Framebuffer` to a `u64`?

Answer (score 1):

`NonZeroU64` has implemented `From<NonZeroU32>` and `u64` has implemented `From<NonZeroU64>` so you can use `from` method of these two types to safely convert the type. Here is a brief example.

```
use std::num::*;
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NativeFrameBuffer(NonZeroU32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct User(u64);

fn test(u:User) {
    println!("{:?}", u);
}

fn main() {
    let u32num = NonZeroU32::new(10u32).unwrap();
    let fb = NativeFrameBuffer(u32num);
    test(User(u64::from(NonZeroU64::from(fb.0))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
    pub  fn unwrap_color_attachment(&self) -> u32 {
        #[cfg(not(target_os = "wasm"))]
        unsafe { mem::transmute(self.color_attachment) }
    }
```

`egui::Image::new(User(my_framebuffer_wrapper.unwrap_color_attachment() as u64), egui::Vec2::new(1280.0, 720.0));`

unsafe is required

Comment: Very bad idea. According to [the docs for `transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/mem/fn.transmute.html): _Both types must have the same size_ so you can't transmute a 32-bit value into a 64-bit value.

Comment: sorry i actually transmuted to u32 then safe casted to u64. I have updated my answer